# Python: My try/except block always return True

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I run the `_create_system_cobbler` function by itself in a standalone script, I'm able to capture the error. In this case, I am simulating an error and it's going to tell me that the dns name I'm using already exist. However, if I put it into a function and make the call from my `main` function, it always return `True`. I

## Error:

```
Error! <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>:'dns-name duplicated: inadmin001.domain.local'
```

## _create_system_cobbler function

```
def _create_system_cobbler():
    try:
        cobbler_server = xmlrpclib.Server("https://127.0.0.1/cobbler_api")
    except socket.error:
        print "Can't Connect to Cobbler"
        quit()

    serverinfo = {
        'hostname' : 'inadmin001',
        'macaddress': '00:2e:4e:78:ba:86',
        'ipaddress': '172.21.10.33',
        'dnsname': 'inadmin001.domain.local'
    }

    try:
        token = cobbler_server.login("cobbler","cobbler")
        system_id = cobbler_server.new_system(token)
        ...
        <more code>
        ...
    except xmlrpclib.Fault as err:
        errormsg = "Error " + str(err.faultString)
        return False, errormsg

    return True, serverinfo
```

## Main Function

```
def main(session)
    handler, serverinfo = _create_system_cobbler()
    if handler:
        print "Let's create a VM"
        print serverinfo
        # Let's continue with the rest of the code
    else:
        print serverinfo
        quit()
```

Comment: You should not use return flags in python,  use try...  except instead.

Comment: @MaxNoe try..except was used. I think the problem is that `raise` is needed instead of `return`

Comment: I don't know why you are getting different behavior, but I wanted to comment on your design: don't handle exceptions by returning False. Just let the exception propagate, and let the caller deal with it. If you want to add information, Python 3 has raise ... from: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/ Otherwise, you can "manually" wrap the inner exception with your own. E.g. try: asplode() except Explosion as e: raise MoreDetailedExplosion('more information', e)

Comment: He surely uses a return flag to check if the handler was successfully created,  this is not very pythonic

Comment: I'm guessing that there is something else (i.e. something you haven't shown us) in your program that is affecting the behavior.

Comment: are you sure that your code go into the exception?

Comment: So if i'm not supposed to `return` things, what's the better way of handling this? I need to capture the error and display it before I can continue w/ the rest of the code. My problem is, I'm not sure how to handle the `if/else` portion in the `main` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using return codes is not very pythonic, you should write the function assuming everything goes well and `except` exceptions outside:

```
def create_system_cobbler():

    cobbler_server = xmlrpclib.Server("https://127.0.0.1/cobbler_api")

    serverinfo = {
        'hostname' : 'inadmin001',
        'macaddress': '00:2e:4e:78:ba:86',
        'ipaddress': '172.21.10.33',
        'dnsname': 'inadmin001.domain.local'
    }

    token = cobbler_server.login("cobbler","cobbler")
    system_id = cobbler_server.new_system(token)
    ...
    <more code>
    ...

    return cobbler_server


def main(session):
    try:
        handler = create_system_cobbler()
    except socket.error:
        print("Can't Connect to Cobbler")
    except xmlrpclib.Fault as err:
        print('Error: ', err)
```

Comment: Ah I see. I wasn't sure where the `try/except` block should go. It makes sense now. Thanks a lot.